# How to access fields for the Registrant settings (RNG)

Tags: entities, rng

At the RNG module there is a possibility at the Settings to add fields to the Registrant settings. As I understand the idea behind this is to add some fields to the registrant. I want to add a color to the registrant.
But how can I access these fields? After I register for an event I can see my registrants on the Registration List, but I can't see the additional fields.  I also have no idea how to add the content to these fields?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I access these fields?

As I'm sure you are aware, you can add the fields here at

`Administration > Configuration > RNG > Registrant settings > Manage fields` (/admin/config/rng/registrant/fields)

> I can see my registrants on the Registration List, but I can't see the additional fields.

The registration list page is simply a page provided by Views. There are a few ways to edit the view, including the quick edit button which appears on the right side of the page. On the view, there is already a pre-made relationship from `event entity -> registrant entities -> identity entity`. The fields added to any of the entity types, including the registrant entity type, should be automatically available by using the standard Views add field button.

> I also have no idea how to add the content to these fields?

Before of 1.2, there was no **edit registrant entity** form (or view registrant entity). Adding field values programmatically to registrant entities is also fully supported using the standard Drupal entity API.

I have created an issue for RNG which can be used to discuss this kind of feature: [Add a way to view and edit registrants entities](https://github.com/dpi/rng/issues/90)